# Track push notifications in Firebase (using react-native-fcm)

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification

I use `react-native-fcm presentLocalNotification()` function to show push notification on phone.

I also want to track `notification_dismiss`, `notification_foreground`, `notification_open` and `notification_receive` events in Firebase.
It is written in the documentation that these events are collected automatically https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en. But I don't see them in Events in Analytics (through I see automatic `first_open`, `app_remove` events ).
Could you advise what to do in order to see/track these notification events in Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is that you should try https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase. This works well for me using features of firebase such as notification, analtyics and database, etc. It also tracks automatically of `notification_dismiss, notification_foreground, notification_open` and `notification_receive`.

Comment: I found an example with local and remote notifications that are created using RNF https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/blob/firebase/Examples/firebase-migration/app/App.js .  I see that local notifications do not require any authorization, will they be tracked in Firebase Analytics? Should I necessarily use remote notification in order to track events? Right now local notifications work fine for me and don't need any other types.

Comment: I've never tested for this using react-native-fcm. Sorry for my very late response.